# MIPS Pipeline Cpu Architecture

Tags: mips, cpu, computer-science, pipeline, cpu-architecture

I'm dealing with the following exercise on which I can't really get my head around and any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Considering this CPU:[image]

I have to:

1. Determine how many total clock cycles are needed to complete all the instructions.
2. Determine the content of the **ID/EX** register after 6 cc(clock cycles) since the beginning of the fist instruction.

These are the instructions:
        `0x450: addi $1, $4, -1`
           `lw   $2, 0($1)`
           `lw   $3, 0($2)`
           `sw   $3, 80($1)`

I've tried to answer to the first question creating a pipeline diagram with the 5 stages(Fetch, Decode, Execute, Memory access, Write back) and this is what I've done:

```
                |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5  |  6 |  7 |  8  |  9 | 10  |
addi $1, $4, -1 | IF | ID | EX |  M |  W  |    |    |     |    |     |
lw $2, 0($1)    |    | IF | ID | EX |  M  |  W |    |     |    |     |
lw $3, 0($2)    |    |    | IF | *  |  ID | EX |  M |  W  |    |     |
sw $3, 80($1)   |    |    |    | IF |  *  | *  | ID |  EX |  M |  W  |
```

So I've answered 10 clock cycles.

If the first one is right(which I cannot be sure if it is) I'd really need some help in the second one regarding the content of the **ID/EX** register.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your answer to the first part of the question seems correct. The pipeline would insert bubbles when a RAW hazard is created with a Load instruction (as the result of the instruction is only available after the MEM stage of the pipe).

Since you have the entire pipeline in front of you, it shouldn't be hard to figure out the contents of ID/EX register after cycle 6. The contents would correspond to the store instruction. Given this it should be fairly easy to figure out the contents now.

Comment: So, just to be sure, after 6 CC we should have this as the content of the ID/EX register: 0x462 (PC), and then $1, 80 (offset) and then $3 (dest- reg), correct? @rahul-behl